# ASP website not rendering style when redirected to log-in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am a little lost of why my log-in page is not rendering the styling when the default page is redirected to it.

1: is the *page I get* when I load my website from VS.

2: is the *page I should get*. (I do get the styling when I enter the log-in page direct URL)

What do I have to do to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that css file is generated from a asp page? The default webserver from VS doesn't support asp files.

Things you can check: is the css file called? (network inspector)
Is the html of the login page completely valid?
Is it an internal redirect or external redirect? A internal redirect can have a different location and therefore maybe unable to locate the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path to your CSS file is correctly specified in your login page.

Comment: Can you detect anything when loading one of the browser developer tools (F12 on IE9, Developer Tools in Chrome)? It will show you the CSS it is using for any of the elements on the page.